# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range - only when Excel VBE is closed

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, subscript

All,

I am facing an error with a some VBA code in an Excel macro. Here’s the workflow I am attempting:

- I have a module that runs code to create a new worksheet, format it and add in a bunch of values
- within this same module, I determine a range of cells based on the last row populated (which will always be different depending upon previous steps)
- Once I know this range, I use the code below to write to the newly created worksheets codemodule so I can set up a ‘change_event’. I only want the change_event to trigger when the values in the range I just determined are changed:`

  ```
  Dim Startline As Long
  Startline = 1
  Dim x As Integer
  x = Errors.Count - 1

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Range("D" & LastRow - x & ":" & "D" & LastRow)

         With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(VRS.CodeName).CodeModule
          Startline = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet") + 1
          .InsertLines Startline, "Dim rng As Range "
          Startline = Startline + 1
          .InsertLines Startline, "Set rng = Range(" & """" & CStr(rng.Address) & """" & ")"
          Startline = Startline + 1
          .InsertLines Startline, "If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub"
          Startline = Startline + 1
          .InsertLines Startline, "If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub"
          Startline = Startline + 1
          .InsertLines Startline, "MsgBox (""Value Changed!..."") "
         End With
  ```

The code works, and writes the following into the codemodule of the specified worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("D58:D62")
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub  
If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
MsgBox ("Value Changed!...") 
End Sub`
```

This code works too, and the message box appears when the cells in the range are changed. However, with the VBE **closed** it will produce the the error:

```
Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
```

Hitting debug takes me to the the line:

```
With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(WS.CodeName).CodeModule
```

But it actually throws the error on the following line:

```
Startline = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet") + 1
```

Comment: Ok, so i modified the code to simply delete all code from the specified worksheet and re-write instead of deleting and writing fresh each time. This prevents the error from popping up, but automatically opens the VBE instead.... I use the line below to close the VBE...not very slick though. I'm open to a more graceful solution:   Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA changing sheet codename Run-Time Error 9: Subscript out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022319/vba-changing-sheet-codename-run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're getting that error, but here's another approach that will avoid it

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sCode As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set rng = ws.Range("D1:D10")

    sCode = "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    sCode = sCode & vbTab & "Dim rng As Range" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    sCode = sCode & vbTab & "Set rng = Me.Range(" & """" & rng.Address & """" & ")" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    sCode = sCode & vbTab & "If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub" & vbNewLine
    sCode = sCode & vbTab & "If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    sCode = sCode & vbTab & "MsgBox (""Value Changed!..."") " & vbNewLine
    sCode = sCode & "End Sub"

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.CodeName).CodeModule.AddFromString sCode

End Sub
```