# How to Rename Sheet Name in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In a workbook I was given, in VBA window I can see sheet names are customized as below. Could anyone tell me how this is done, please? I think normally the names are like Sheet1, Sheet2, etc. Moreover, in VBA coding, these sheet names are used. For example, `Ws.Name <> shCover.Name`

[image]

Comment: @ScottCraner Then how to change the code name, please? If I create a new workbook, the code name is usually like Sheet1(Sheet1).

Comment: In the Properties window, by `(Name)`.

Comment: Also by vba: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022319/changing-sheet-codename-run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range